# Transmit Automator Actions Not Loading

Tags: macos, automator, ftp

I have been using Panic Transmit to upload files from a specific folder to an S3 bucket for quite a while (couple of years). I have run into an issue where the Automator actions associated with Panic won't load (I think this is an apple Quarantine problem). When I open automator and try to use the upload action, for example, I see the following:

[image: "Upload" is an action downloaded from the internet. Are you sure you want to load it?]

The problem is that when I click Load, nothing happens at all. I've tried restarting to no avail. I ran into this problem a couple weeks ago and reinstalled Transmit, and remade all my folder actions. This worked, but I'd rather not do this every time this happens. I also can't find the action saved in any of the normal locations, so I'm not sure how to turn quarantine off for it.

I'm running OSX 10.10.5 with Transmit 4.4.1. The only thing in the Workflow is the "Upload" action from Transmit. I am uploading to a saved favorite in Transmit.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. Could you edit some details into the question? Version of the app and the OS X machine you are running? Could you share the automator setup - what specific code is programmed? I bet several people could try to reproduce your setup and let you know if it's a coding error in the script itself.

Answer (score 1):

So I figured this out after a lot of digging. In looking for the Automator action, I somehow skimmed over the application package in /Applications.

Transmit's actions live in `/Applications/Transmit.app/Contents/Library/Automator`.

Once I found them, I just had to clear the Apple quarantine info on that folder with 
`sudo xattr -r -d com.apple.quarantine /Applications/Transmit.app/Contents/Library/Automator` [source](https://derflounder.wordpress.com/2012/11/20/clearing-the-quarantine-extended-attribute-from-downloaded-applications/).

I Hope this helps anyone with the same problem in the future!

Comment: Great answer. Thank you you are a legend for sharing this gem of insight.